# Link in the Anchor Tag is not working Properly

Tags: c#, html, sql-server-2008

We are having some links to Social Network sites in our Website the Web address of the sites are stored in the database and we are fetching it during runtime and assiging the web address of the site to the href of anchor tag in Server-side coding as 
`str.Append("<a href='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["URL"].ToString() + "' target='_blank'><img border='0' src='" + filename + "'/></a>");`
and during runtime it was created as 
`<a target="_blank" href="www.facebook.com">
<img border="0" src="http://Server_Name/FTPsite//Folder_Name/Facebook_Logo.png">
</a>` but when we click on that link it comes as **localhost/www.facebook.com** instead of just **http://www.facebook.com** what might be going wrong here kindly help.

Comment: Did you try replace "www." at the beginning of str with "http://". Another point, consider to use [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) for composing strings with parameters

Comment: @YoYo I had tried the webaddress without "www." also but the same result "http://Server_Name/facebook.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `'http://'` string before the site's url:

`str.Append("<a href='http://" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["URL"].ToString() + "' target='_blank'><img border='0' src='" + filename + "'/></a>");`

Althoug the best you could do is to make sure all your url in your database begin with `http://`

Comment: It would be a better idea to add the `http://` prefix to the url in the database and not in that method. If you had an url with it already it would crash.